# Calculo DataFrame Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Ola, gostaria de uma ajuda com Pandas em uma DataFrame

```
         Tipo CreatedDate   CompanyName TotalRepasseACia
1969    Flight  2022-01       KLM           3531.49
1970    Flight  2022-01    LATAM AIRLINES    324.96
1971    Flight  2022-01    DELTA AIRLINES   2635.07
1972    Flight  2022-01    COPA AIRLINES    1311.68
1973    Flight  2022-01    UNITED AIRLINES  3653.16
```

Eu ganho uma comissao especifica por cada CompanyName e fiz assim:

```
for i in df['CompanyName']:
    if i == 'KLM':
        df['Comissao'] = df['TotalRepasseACia']*0.02
    elif i == 'LATAM AIRLINES':
        df['Comissao'] = df['TotalRepasseACia']*0.06
    elif i == 'DELTA AIRLINES':
        df['Comissao'] = df['TotalRepasseACia']*0.09
    elif i == 'COPA AIRLINES':
        df['Comissao'] = df['TotalRepasseACia']*0.02
    elif i == 'UNITED AIRLINES':
        df['Comissao'] = df['TotalRepasseACia']*0.01
    else:
        df['Comissao'] = 0
```

Mas o resultado nao estah o esperando, veja:

```
    Tipo    CreatedDate CompanyName TotalRepasseACia    Comissao
    Flight  2022-01         KLM          3531.49         35.3149
    Flight  2022-01     LATAM AIRLINES    324.96          3.2496
    Flight  2022-01     DELTA AIRLINES   2635.07         26.3507
    Flight  2022-01     COPA AIRLINES    1311.68         13.1168
    Flight  2022-01     UNITED AIRLINES  3653.16         36.5316
```

O calculo esta mal. esta calculando pelo ultimo valor, nao esta considerando que tenho uma percentual diferente.

Eu gostaria que na coluna Comissao, estivesse os valores calculado sobre [TotalRepasseACia]* comissao por cada CompanyName.

Answer (score -2):

Consegui resolver. vou colocar para outras pessoas se precisarem

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['CompanyName'] == 'KLM':
        df.loc[index, 'Comissao'] = df.loc[index,'TotalRepasseACia']*0.0
    elif row['CompanyName'] == 'LATAM AIRLINES':
        df.loc[index, 'Comissao'] = df.loc[index,'TotalRepasseACia']*0.01
    elif row['CompanyName'] == 'AEROLINEAS ARGENTINAS':
        df.loc[index, 'Comissao'] = df.loc[index,'TotalRepasseACia']*0.03
    elif row['CompanyName'] == 'AMERICAN AIRLINES':
        df.loc[index, 'Comissao'] = df.loc[index,'TotalRepasseACia']*0.04
    elif row['CompanyName'] == 'GOL LINHAS AEREAS':
        df.loc[index, 'Comissao'] = df.loc[index,'TotalRepasseACia']*0.01
```

Comment: A partir da pergunta não é possível determinar uma solução pois não foi informada uma tabela de porcentagens para as companhias e os coeficientes usados na pergunta e na sua respostas são diferentes. Também não foi informado se os valores da coluna `TotalRepasseACia` podem ser ou não diferentes para uma companhia. Mesmo não podendo determinar uma solução analisando sua resposta é possível especular que a maneira que 
resolveu não é a forma mais eficiente. Em pandas quando possível deve-se evitar iterações e preferir código vetorizado https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/airline#main.py